# Netbeans 7.4: Signed APK and IPA files

Tags: android, ios, netbeans, cordova

I recently installed NetBeans 7.4 which now allows Android and iOS development with PhoneGap (Cordova) integration.

I can run the apps perfectly but how can I export the signed apk and ipa file for distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for android market i am using Android Studio from Google. Advise you as it came from the source. Very easy to install an use. You can zipalign your app so it is in smaller size. Hope it is in any help for you.

Comment: will start to deal with iOS in the middle of November. Will post you solution than

Comment: it is possible to pack a phonegap app with Android Studio?

Comment: @mohamnag yes actually it is very easy to do it. You can pack your app, sign it and also zip align it so it reduce the size of the app. Go to > build > Generate signed APK. you have to generate your key and thats all.

Comment: I have to use that then. I'm asking myself why isn't that possible to be done in netbeans itself.

Comment: I found Android studio really easy to use and as much is developed by Google you can expect that all updates are incorporated. My advice is to use Google Studio. If you don't want but you already have development APK from google you can do it on command prompt.